# useSWR returning response instead of response.data with Axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I'm new to useSWR, and trying to figure out its benefits. So far, I feel like my refactoring is causing me quite a headache, and one that came up again is that I am not receiving the data from the hook that I expect.
If you see the screenshot, in one hook I get the proper data, and the other one, I get the whole response from axios. It doesn't show on the screenshot, but I have tried using the same axiosInstance on both fetcher, and things are the same.

[image]

I have also tried to add a async/await on the fetcher, still the same. Any idea?
My workaround is to type and refactor the parsed response., so I get instead
`data.data.result`instead.

Answer (score 0):

What fixes my issue was actually to close/kill the app, then re-start it. It give me the expected result only then...
This answered my question, but leads to another one... why? ^^'